# iOS5: MPMoviePlayerController VIDEO ONLY, NO AUDIO

Tags: ipad, media-player, ios5

*This is not the No video, audio only problem*. It's just the **opposite**.
The problem arises when using iOS 5.0. iPads running 4.3 or lower play the same video files flawlessly.

since iOS 5 changed the way stuff is  initialized for MPMoviePlayerControllers, I had to do some SDK based programming in order to get the video to be displayed. Before implementing the snippet I'm showing next, the video and it's controls won't even show up on the screen. The controller would only show a black square with the size and origin of given CGRect frame.

The way I handle it is the following:

The video files are located on the documents folder. So the NSURL has to be initialized as fileURLWithPath. Once that's done, I proceed to initialized the controller with a given frame. Since it wouldn't work otherwise, the view will only add the player once it has changed its loadState. That's achieve by subscribing to a notification. the subscriber selector performs the addition of the controller's view to the parent view **on the main thread** since the notification could be handled from other threads.

Initializing and adding video to the view:

```
-(void)addVideo:(NSString*) videoName onRect:(CGRect)rect {

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    iPadMagazineAppDelegate *appDelegate = GET_APP_DELEGATE;
    NSArray *dirArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *dirName = [dirArray objectAtIndex:0];

    // get directory name for this issue
    NSURL *baseURL; 

    /* 
     BUGFIX: Video does not work on iOS 5.0

     */
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"5.0")){
        baseURL = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:dirName]URLByAppendingPathComponent:[appDelegate.currentIssue getIssueDirectoryName ]];
    }else {
        baseURL = [[NSURL URLWithString:dirName] URLByAppendingPathComponent:[appDelegate.currentIssue getIssueDirectoryName]];
    }

    /* end  BUGFIX: Video does not work on iOS 5.0 */

    NSURL *videoURL = [baseURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:videoName];    


    MPMoviePlayerController * movieController= [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:videoURL];

    // set frame for player
    movieController.view.frame = rect;

    // set  auto resizing masks
    [movieController.view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];

    // don't auto play.
    [movieController setShouldAutoplay:NO];

    [movieController setUseApplicationAudioSession:YES];

    /*
     BUGFIX: Video does not work on iOS 5.0
     */
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"5.0")) {
        [movieController prepareToPlay];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(loadVideo:) name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:movieController];  
    }else {
        [pdfView addSubview:movieController.view];
        [pdfView bringSubviewToFront: movieController.view];
    }

    /* end  BUGFIX: Video does not work on iOS 5.0 */

    [_moviePlayerViewControllerArray addObject:movieController];
    [movieController release];
    [pool release];
}
```

notification handler:

```
-(void)loadVideo:(NSNotification*)notification {

    for (MPMoviePlayerController *movieController in _moviePlayerViewControllerArray) {

        if (movieController.loadState != MPMovieLoadStateUnknown) {


            [pdfView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addSubview:) withObject:movieController.view waitUntilDone:YES];
            [pdfView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(bringSubviewToFront:) withObject:movieController.view waitUntilDone:YES];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:movieController];
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you for reading this huge question. I appreciate your answers.

cheers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently there's a bug, but it's not related to the MPMoviePlayerController, but to iOS 5 itself.

My iPad was muted from the switch but still played audio from iPod app anyway so I didn't realized that it was that way, so MPMoviePlayerController was fine, but part of the OS did not notice that the iPad was muted.

I've filed the corresponding bug on Apple's bug tracker.  Bug ID# 10368531.

I Apologize if I've wasted your time.

UPDATE: Got feedback from apple for the bug. It's expected behavior.  :\

Comment: Thanks Pacu, that helped me a lot. To be precise, I had to do the following on my iPad 2 running 5.0.1: 1) in Settings change side switch to control Muting, 2) mute and unmute it, 3) Test out my app to hear the sound work properly, 4) back to Settings so side switch controls orientation again, 5) back to app to verify that sound still works. Thanks!

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue on iOS 7. Do you have any idea why this issue is still there??? I am only getting audio not video??

Comment: It's expected behaviour. That mean that Apple wants the system to do that. If you have your device muted, you won't be able to play any audio from your player VC.

Answer (score 13):

Try this:
Set MPMoviePlayerController's property "useApplicationAudioSession" to "NO".

Comment: Warning, not only does doing this override the mute switch, but this property is deprecated in 6.0.  You should make sure that your problem isn't due to having the mute switch set.

Comment: hey, what about ios 7? this property is deprecated